# Find a basis for W={p(x)=a+bx+cx^2:p(1)=p'(-1)=0}

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find a basis for $W=\{p(x)=a+bx+cx^2:p(1)=p'(-1)=0\}.$

So I begin by $p(1)=c+b+a=0$ and then $p'(1)=2c+b$.

I am then suppose to find the spanning set for W using that.  However, I have no idea what I'm suppose to do.
I think $p(x)$ is suppose to be of the form:

$p(x)=(-3c)+(-2c)x+c(x^2)
=c(x^2-2x-3)$

> But I have absolutely $0$ idea how someone would get from the $p(1)$ and $p'(1)$ to the form of $p(x)$.

For some reason I cannot "Add Comment".  I will just type it here:  Basis for p(x) is just ${1,x,x^2}$

Comment: Maybe you can start by finding a basis for $p(x)$={$a+bx+cx^2$}. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, $p'(-1) = 0$ iff $(x+1) \mid p'(x)$, whence
$$
p'(x) = a(x+1)
$$
So $p(x) = c(x+1)^2 +d$.

Now $p(1) = 0$, so $4c + d = 0 \Rightarrow d = -4c$, so
$$
p(x) = c\{(x+1)^2 - 4\}
$$
Hence
$$
W = \operatorname{span}\{(x+1)^2-4\}
$$

Answer (score 0):

We can start with a basis for the set $p(x)$={$a+bx+cx^2$} , the space of polynomials of degree $\leq 2$. A standard basis is $B=${$1,x,x^2$} , because every element in $p(x)$ can be written as a linear combination of  elements of $B$, and the elements of $B$ are linearly-independent. Now, things change when you have the additional condition that $p(1)=p'(1)=0$ ; this condition restricts the collection $p(x)$ to a subcollection, say $p_2(x)$ of $p(x)$. Can you see how to do it?